# Database Connection Failed You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, database-connection

I am creating an edit profile page where the logged in user can edit the profile. I now run into the error below. what do i do?

ERROR:

```
Database Connection FailedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'test@hotmail.com', Password = 'test', FirstName = 'hello', SecondName = 'world' at line 1
```

My code:

```
            <?php
            $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbrateme');  
            if (!$connection){ 
                die("Database Connection Failed" . mysql_error());
                        header('Location: dcf.php');
            }
            $select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbrateme'); 
            if (!$select_db){ 
                die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error());  
            }

            if (isset($_POST['upd'])){ 
                        $course = $_POST['Course'];
                        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];
                        $password = $_POST['inputPassword'];
                        $FN = $_POST['FirstName'];
                        $SN = $_POST['SecondName']; 

                    $qsql = $_COOKIE['userID'];
                    $qresult = mysqli_query($connection, $qsql);
                    $qcount = mysqli_connect($qresult);
                    $sqli = "UPDATE tblaccounts Email = '".$email."', Password = '".$password."', FirstName = '".$FN."', SecondName = '".$SN."', Course = '".$course."' WHERE Student_ID='".$qsql."'";

                    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sqli) or die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
                    //$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    echo "Profile Update Successful!:";
                    header('Location: profile.php');
            } else { 
                        echo "Profile Update Failed!:";
                        ?><br/><a href ="updatesettigns.php">Go back to the profile update screen.</a><?php
                    }
            ?>
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: This is a typo question; you missed `SET`.

Answer (score 1):

You miss the keyword set in your SQL. Syntax for Update is `UPDATE <table> SET <colum Name> = value`

```
$sqli = "UPDATE tblaccounts SET Email = '".$email."', Password = '".$password."', FirstName = '".$FN."', SecondName = '".$SN."', Course = '".$course."' WHERE Student_ID='".$qsql."'";
```

Learn about prepared stateemnts to prevent SQL injection.

Never store passwords as plain text. Use function to encrypt them

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the query, but my god are you open to a serious case of sql injection. To target the first issue.

```
UPDATE tblaccounts Email
```

Change this to

```
UPDATE tblaccounts SET Email
```

The query you are using is vulnerable to sql injection. You should fix this as soon as possible. I would suggest using PDO prepared statements for all of your SQL queries. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: *I would suggest using PDO prepared statements*  Why PDO? mysqli can also handle prepared statements.

Comment: PDO is a much nicer syntax and is a far easier library to use, just my opinion though